# Sorting out raw data from an API link in PHP that is in JSON format

Tags: php, api, formatting, explode, json

Hopefully this will be quite an easy one for you here.

Anyway, I have been having alot of trouble with fread() so have decided to use an api link that I have been able to locate.

The script is simply to convert extracted game server data into a readable format.

The link for the "Serialized" data is : http://api.typefish.co.uk/monitor/sa-mp/80.86.81.14:6969/?info&masterlist&rules&players

Simply put I have very little in the way of ideas on what I can do with this data.

So far this is what I have although I am probably miles off:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://api.typefish.co.uk/monitor/sa-mp/80.86.81.14:6969/?info&masterlist&rules&players");
trim($content, "{");
trim($content, "}");
foreach(exlpode(",", $content) as $pieces){
  explode(":", $pieces);
}
```

And now I am stuck. Can someone either tell me a way thats miles better or help me finish off the script with some ideas?

Thanks

This is the code I have now after 2 answers:

```
    $newarray = json_decode($content);
    var_dump($newarray);
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $newarray->{"mapname"};
```

The problem is that I am unable to display the variable in this format, how can I rebuild that so I can view the variables.

I have changed this:

```
echo $newarray->{"mapname"};
```

to this:

```
echo $newarray->data->rules->mapname;
```

Comment: so I have added the code suggested in 2 answers but still do not have a way to access the data to be able to format it, I am adding the format attempt I have made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data is in json format. All you need to use to convert it into a php Array is `json_decode($content)`

Reference: https://www.php.net/json_decode
And read more about json here: http://www.json.org/

Comment: thanks to 2 answers already! I will investigate BOTH answers and select the answer that is closest to what I end up using (if it works which im sure it will)

Comment: I have created the code as suggested but also been unable to view the content of the arrays variables individually. are you able to add a way to view? I have unsuccessfully tried 3 ways now.

Comment: How are you trying to access them? Which indexes specifically are you trying to access?

Comment: I have added the details to the bottom of the question

Comment: This converts the data completely to a php array. Access like this: `$newarray['data']['rules']['mapname']`

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: My bad, the correct way would be $newarray->data->rules->mapname

Comment: result! Thanks for that, I will now attempt  to create a script to format that data. just quickly can i do a foreach on one of those variable thingys with $n so that i can loop on it or is there a different way of looping required for that format?

Answer (score 0):

You ar doing it wrong, it's not PHP serialized string, its json output you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get string into PHP array.

Like:

```
var_dump(json_decode($content, true));
```